# unknown configuration line "INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(dkim-milter, S=inet:8891@localhost)"

Tags: sendmail, dkim

I followed a tutorial using the socket connection dkim-milter to sign my outgoing mail. I did it and the conf file loaded fine. But I discovered that my mail were not signed. I found many other tutorial advising to use inet:8891@localhost instead of socket. I thought maybe that could be the reason why it's not signed. I did all the config changes to my dkim-milter file and to my sendmail mc passed by m4 but since I changed `S=/something/to/socket` to `S=inet:8891@localhost` I get unkown configuration line.

exact error message containing the line is:

```
Starting sendmail: 554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: 
line 1: unknown configuration line "INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(dkim-milter, S=inet:8891@localhost)"
```

I discovered that the line

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(dkim-milter, S=inet:8891@localhost)
```

get written as is in the sendmail.cf file upon m4 process. I doubt that this is the correct thing that should happen.

**SOLUTION ?**

I finally erased INPUT_MAIL_FILTER  that was correctly commented out and past the option line I wanted after

> include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl

I dont know what could be the reason but it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had entered the INPUT_MAIL_FILTER line between a `divert(-1)` and a `divert(0)` line then it gets written verbatim in your `sendmail.cf`. You place configuration commands after a `divert(0)` in your `sendmail.mc`. And even then, sometimes the order of the commands matters.